# Forcing matrix to have even dimensions without conditional

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I am looking for a clever way to *force* the dimensions (both nrow and ncol) of a matrix to be even **without using an if statement**. By *force* I mean subtract the first appropriate column and/or row so that both dimensions are even.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
 ## build a matrix with odd number of columns and even number of rows
 x=matrix(1:12,nrow=4,ncol=3)

 ## we can check which (if any) dimensions are odd with
 dim(x) %% 2 ## 0,1

 ## I would like get a matrix that looks like 
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    5    9
 [2,]    6   10
 [3,]    7   11
 [4,]    8   12

 ## By using something similar to 
 x.even = x[-nrow(x)%%2,-ncol(x)%%2]
```

Obviously the last line does not give the desired result.  Is there a clever way to do this without using a conditional?

Comment: `x.even = x[1:(2*floor(nrow(x)/2)),1:(2*floor(ncol(x)/2))]`

Comment: I love it! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide `nrow` and `ncol` by `2`, take `floor`, and multiply by `2` again

```
x.even = x[1:(2*floor(nrow(x)/2)),1:(2*floor(ncol(x)/2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that builds on your solution:

```
#start rows and columns from 1
#also subtract remainder from total rows and columns  
x[1:(nrow(x) - nrow(x) %% 2), 1:(ncol(x) - ncol(x) %% 2)]
```

output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8
```